# Mounting NFS-server running in VM: Connection timed out

Tags: linux, virtualization, nfs, virtualbox, vmware-workstation

I have stumbled upon this general problem with NFS in virtualized machines it seems.
Long story short, I tried to roll up a FOG-server, that uses NFS.

- The NFS-server VM-host is in bridged mode with IP: 10.0.0.136
- can mount the NFS-share from other VMs on the physical host, but not from other LAN-devices.
- The virtual machine is in NAT Bridge-mode no matter what VM-platform I use.
- Firewall disabled - ports.. are.. open..
- The physical machine running the VM-platform is a Windows 10 Home, disabled firewall and Intel-network adapter.

**The problem:**
When I mount from other LAN-devices I get 'Connection timed out', but showmount responds after 2 min and 10 sec.
This test is performed from a Synology-NAS on the same LAN-network.

```
# mount -v -t nfs nfsserver:/images /volume1/test
mount.nfs: timeout set for Tue Jan 30 23:43:55 2018
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=3,tcp,soft,nolock,addr=10.0.0.136'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.0.0.136 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.0.0.136 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 56755
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection timed out
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=3,tcp,soft,nolock,addr=10.0.0.136'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.0.0.136 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.0.0.136 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 56755
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection timed out
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=3,tcp,soft,nolock,addr=10.0.0.136'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.0.0.136 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.0.0.136 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 56755

# showmount -e nfsserver
Export list for 10.0.0.136:
/images/dev 10.0.0.0/24
/images     10.0.0.0/24
```

It works as intended, when I mount from another VM-host on the same VMplatform - in this case Debian 9/VirtualBox:
Instant mount and instant 'showmount -e'-response.

```
# mount -vt nfs nfsserver:/images /mnt/test
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Jan 31 01:03:30 2018
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=10.0.0.136,clientaddr=10.0.0.108'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=10.0.0.136'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.0.0.136 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 10.0.0.136 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 33485
```

This is my /etc/exports on the nfsserver:

```
# cat /etc/exports
/images 10.0.0.0/24(ro,sync,no_wdelay,no_subtree_check,insecure_locks,no_root_squash,insecure,fsid=0)
/images/dev 10.0.0.0/24(rw,async,no_wdelay,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,insecure,fsid=1)
```

This is the firewall (disabled):

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The services are listening:

```
# rpcinfo -p
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100005    1   udp  48327  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  47113  mountd
    100005    2   udp  50106  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  46029  mountd
    100005    3   udp  38832  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  46131  mountd
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   tcp   2049
    100227    3   tcp   2049
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   udp   2049
    100227    3   udp   2049
    100021    1   udp  36259  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  36259  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  36259  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  45767  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  45767  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  45767  nlockmgr
```

A portscan from a LAN-device timing out, shows open ports:

```
# nmap -p 111,2049 -T4 -A nfsserver
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-01-31 00:22 CET
Nmap scan report for nfsserver (10.0.0.136)
Host is up (0.00079s latency).
rDNS record for 10.0.0.136: nfsserver
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
111/tcp  open  rpcbind 2-4 (RPC #100000)
| rpcinfo:
|   program version   port/proto  service
|   100000  2,3,4        111/tcp  rpcbind
|   100000  2,3,4        111/udp  rpcbind
|   100003  2,3,4       2049/tcp  nfs
|   100003  2,3,4       2049/udp  nfs
|   100005  1,2,3      38832/udp  mountd
|   100005  1,2,3      46131/tcp  mountd
|   100021  1,3,4      36259/udp  nlockmgr
|   100021  1,3,4      45767/tcp  nlockmgr
|   100227  2,3         2049/tcp  nfs_acl
|_  100227  2,3         2049/udp  nfs_acl
2049/tcp open  nfs_acl 2-3 (RPC #100227)
Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.33 seconds
```

`/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` are both empty:

```
# cat /etc/hosts.allow /etc/hosts.deny
#
```

So far I've replicated the problem on:

- RHEL 7 / VirtualBox
- Debian 9 / VirtualBox
- Fedora 13 / VirtualBox
- Debian 9 / VMWare Workstation Player 14
- Ubuntu 16 / VMWare Workstation Player 14

It's strange! After trying this for almost a week, I surrender to you, mighty Gods of Serverfault

I'm clueless and humble!

How do I mount to an NFS-server running in a virtual machine without timing out?

**Edit:** Thanks for the formating.
I tried tcpdumping both ends, and it seems some packets never arrive at the NFS-server inside the VM.
It looks like a network issue deep inside virtualbox.
Still clueless though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no clue why this problem happens in VMs, but if I mount with version 3 it works.

`mount -t nfs -o vers=3,nolock,proto=tcp  nfsserver:/images /volume1/test`

Solution found, but not really explainable..?